# Eigenvalues of simultaneously diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two stochastic matrices A and B. These matrices commute and are simultaneously diagonalizable. Let $\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_1$ be two eigenvalues of A corresponding to eigenvectors $x_0$ and $x_1$ with $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_0|$.
Define $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ the eigenvalues of matrix B corresponding, respectively, to the eigenvectors $x_0$ and $x_1$.
Could we say something about the relation between $|\alpha_1|$ and $|\alpha_0|$?